# Dropdown Menu not reflecting in the UI

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

I have been trying to make a form with a **dropdown menu** and a **textfield**.
I have added a list of items in the dropdown menu and whenever I am clicking on the dropdown menu button the list is showing but **when I am trying to select the particular menu item it is not reflecting** and also if **I am trying to select a particular menu item the corresponding textfield hint text should change as per the menu item name.**

I am attaching a very small code snippet which elaborates the method used.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class ContactUs extends StatefulWidget {
  const ContactUs({
    Key key,
    @required this.h,
    @required this.w,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double h;
  final double w;

  @override
  _ContactUsState createState() => _ContactUsState();
}

class _ContactUsState extends State<ContactUs> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String _dropDownValue;
    return Container(
      height: widget.h / 1.4,
      color: AppColors.getWhite(),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Positioned(
            top: 100,
            left: 390,
            child: Container(
              height: widget.h / 2,
              width: widget.w / 2,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white,
                  // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: AppColors.getGrey(),
                      blurRadius: 60.0,
                    ),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 30,
            left: 420,
            child: SizedBox(
              height: widget.h / 6,
              child: VerticalDivider(
                thickness: 5.0,
                color: AppColors.getDeepGrey(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
              top: 120,
              left: 450,
              child: Text('Sample Text jsdgsjghzdgjsg\n gdjsgdsahgdjad')),
          Positioned(
              top: 150,
              left: 470,
              right: 430,
              child: TextField(
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Your Name'),
              )),
          Positioned(
            top: 200,
            left: 470,
            right: 650,
            child: TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Country'),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 200,
            left: 780,
            right: 430,
            child: TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Time'),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 260,
            left: 470,
            right: 650,
            child: DropdownButton<String>(
              isExpanded: true,
              value: _dropDownValue, //add value that is showing your choice
              hint: _dropDownValue == null
                  ? Text('Phone Number')
                  : Text(
                      _dropDownValue,
                      style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        color: AppColors.getBlack(),
                      ),
                    ),
              items: ['Phone Number', 'Email Id'].map((val) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: val,
                  child: Text(
                    val,
                    style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                        fontSize: 15, color: AppColors.getBlack()),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  _dropDownValue = val;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 250,
            left: 740,
            right: 430,
            child: TextField(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Phone Number'),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 350,
            left: 1000,
            child: FlatButton(
              minWidth: widget.w / 10,
              color: AppColors.getBlack(),
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(
                'CONNECT',
                style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                  fontSize: 15,
                  color: AppColors.getWhite(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Move _dropDownValue out of method `build`:

   ```
    class _ContactUsState extends State<ContactUs> {
      String _dropDownValue = null;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        //code  
      }
   ```

   }
2. You need to set `value` to `DropdownButton`

   ```
       DropdownButton<String>(
          isExpanded: true,
          value: _dropDownValue //add value that is showing your choice
          hint: _dropDownValue == null
              ? Text('Phone Number')
              : Text(
                  _dropDownValue,
                  style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    color: AppColors.getBlack(),
                  ),
                ),
          items: ['Phone Number', 'Email Id'].map((val) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: val,
              child: Text(
                val,
                style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                    fontSize: 15, color: AppColors.getBlack()),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              _dropDownValue = val;
            });
          },
        ),
   ```

Comment: And about this
 "I am trying to select a particular menu item the corresponding textfield hint text should change as per the menu item name".
How do I achieve this?

Comment: post full widget please, we're missing something

Comment: Please check have added the complete widget